# Error in demo Android app: "Cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: java, android

I'm working through [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/starting-android-development-creating-todo-app/) but I'm getting this error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'listAdapter'

Here's the method it appears in:

```
private void updateUI() {
    helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
            null,null,null,null,null);

    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.task_view,
            cursor,
            new String[] { TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
            new int[] { R.id.taskTextView},
            0
    );
    this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

I'm sure this is a basic problem, but it's not obvious to me. Where am I going wrong?

Let me know if I haven't included enough code.

Comment: Do you declare `listAdapter` anywhere?

Comment: No, I didn't realise I was required to do that as well as creating the variable on line 8 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first declare `listAdapter`. One way of doing this is inline:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this,
        R.layout.task_view,
        cursor,
        new String[] { TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
        new int[] { R.id.taskTextView},
        0
);
```